# Submit checkbox values from a modal window to the html site in which it is embedded

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, submit, modal-dialog

I want the selected queries in the modal window to be sent to the form in the html site which then calls a servlet for further tasks.
In my case, I tried everything to submit the values to the form but it won´t do.

JavaScript for the modal window and the buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentform; //variable to save the form
$("#dialog").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 700,
    modal: false,
    buttons: {
        Add: function() {
        //tried those variantst, without any success.
        //$("form[name='formular']").submit() 
        //alert("docum");
        currentform.submit();
            //document.forms["formular"].submit();
        $(this).dialog('close');
        //$('#formular').submit();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
$(".openDialog").on("click", function() {
    currentform = $(this).closest('form');
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
});
```

The beginning of the form:

```
<form name="form" action="Servlet" method="post">
```

The button to open the modal window:

```
        <input class="openDialog" id="dialogModal" type="submit" value="Select queries to monitor">
```

The content of the modal window. Basically a loop in which queries are formatted for html with checkboxes.

```
        <div id="dialog" class="scrolldiv" title="Monitor Queries">
        <%=combo %>
    </div>
```

Without the modal windows, the button to submit the value of the checked queries and the queries+checkboxes works.

I can provide further information if needed. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it.

With the help of firebug I found out that the jqueryui plugin was altering the layout of the DOM document:

In Eclipse it was like:

```
<form id="myform" action="dothis">
 <div id="dialog">...</div>
</form>
```

but in firebug you could see that the div was actually out of the form tag.

```
<form id="myform" action="dothis"></form>
<div class="ui-widget"><div class="dialog"></div></div>
```

What I did:

```
<form id="myform" action="dothis">...</form>
<div class="dialog"><form id="alsoMyForm" action="dothis">contentOfModalWindow</form></div>
```